# Smallest n such that $A_n$ contains a subgroup of order $6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**What is the smallest $n$ such that $A_n$ contains an Abelian subgroup of order 6?**

---

Firstly I would rule out n $<$5, since I have proven that $A$<sub>$4$</sub> does not contain a group of order 6. But now I am stuck on proving for $A$<sub>$5$</sub>. I feel like there should be an easier and more straight forward approach rather than proving for all $n$.

Comment: Instead of `$A$<sub>$n$</sub>`, it's quicker to write `$A_n$` to produce $A_n$...

Comment: I would work from above as well, not just below. Clearly $n\leq 8$, since in $A_8$ you have the subgroup generated by $(123456)(78)$. Can you make an order $6$ subgroup in $A_7$? What about $A_6$? Alternatively, look at the different order $6$ subgroups of $S_n$ (which is easier) and then decide for each of those whether they are abelian and entirely contained in $A_n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How do I prove it for $A_5$

Comment: @DerekHolt The question is about an _Abelian_ subgroup

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention! An abelian subgroup of order $6$ is cyclic, so you are looking for an even permutation of order $6$.

Answer (score 3):

How about the subgroup generated by $(123)(45)(67)$ in $A_7$?

Answer (score 1):

The group $A_5$ has one isomorphism class of subgroups of order $6$, which is represented by the "twisted $S_3$" generated by $(123)$ and $(12)(45)$. Since this group is non-abelian, we can exclude $A_5$. The group $A_6$ has again only subgroups of order $6$ isomorphic to $S_3$, the "diagonal $S_3$" and the "twisted $S_3$", see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A6). For $A_7$ see [here](http://schmidt.nuigalway.ie/subgroups/a7.pdf). Indeed, there are elements of order $6$ in $A_7$, namely
$$
(123)(45)(67)=(12)(13)(45)(67),
$$
which is a product of an even number of transpositions.
It has order $lcm(3, 2, 2)=  6$.